# Croppic not instantiating

Tags: javascript, crop

I need to use a cropping tool and opted for Croppic, but the problem is I cannot get it to display anything despite simplest code.

code sample:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <link href="croppic/croppic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="croppic/croppic.js"></script>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var o = {
   uploadUrl: 'path'
  }

  var c = new Croppic('id', o);

  alert(c.id);
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="id" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried the min version too and no luck. I tried in IE11 and chrome and no luck. I tried adding more options and no luck. As is, it displays an empty div 500x500 with black borders.

Note the object gets created because I can access it in memory, and I can display an alert with it's correct id property. I'm really out of ideas here.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

**Problem:**
After a while of looking at it, I realized I made a rookie mistake. The script is running before the div is getting created in the dom, so it was not finding it.

**Solution:**
I put the script after the div and it works fine.

***Note:***
Note this would now fall under pure JavaScript as it has nothing to do with Croppic.

**Other Solutions:**
Also note that another solution is to wrap it in a function and call the function onLoad, or wrap it in jquery's $(document ).ready().